# JavaScript: Triggering Multiple Events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, triggers, onclick

I want to finish this project I was working on for my mom for Valentine's day.

**I want to be able to click an `h2` and have it trigger multiple events, for example making the background color green, changing the font size of `h2` to something bigger like 50px and changing the font size of `h1` to 50px**

I've never triggered multiple events at the same time from an onclick event. I'd love assistance to make mom happy.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1 style="color:purple; 
text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.color='yellow'; this.style.fontSize='40px'; document.body.style.backgroundColor='green';">
    Happy Valentines Day Mom!
  </h1>
  <img src="Source/me.jpg" alt="This is Me" width="300" height="300" align="middle">
  <p align="center" style="color:white;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='';">
    Lots of love and wishes on this day. It is not possible to repay the love that you have given to me. I just can love you, dear mom. Take my lots of love on this Happy Valentine's Day.
  </p>
  <img src="source/mom.jpg" alt="Mom" width="200" height="200" align="middle">
  <h1 style="color:blue; 
text-align:center;" onclick="this.innerHTML='Best Mother Ever!';">
    I love you so much! - J
  </h1>
  <br>
  <h2 id="joke" align="center" style="color:white;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='line-through';" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='';">P.S. I love you more!</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("joke").innerHTML = "P.S.S. you are the best!"'>Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to work with style using a CSS file.

Create a CSS file and set some classes like:

```
h2.valentines {
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
}
```

Then on the `onclick` event you can pass a function to add the class to the element you want, just like this:

```
function addValentineClass() {
    const element = document.getElementById('joke');
    element.className = "valentines";
}
```

Comment: I tried this by adding: 
`onclick="addValentineClass()"`
to h2

Also at the bottom before </body> I added:

`<script>

function addValentineClass() {

    const element = document.getElementById("joke");
    element.className = "valentines";
}
</script>`

to the bottom before </body>

I also added an "styles.css" file to the folder and made sure to include styles.css in the head. **Sadly, upon clicking h2 it doesn't do anything..**

Comment: I will edit my code so you can see everything I changed (besides the CSS file) - it didn't work :(

Comment: You could also add the style directly on the html using the ``<style></style>`` tag.
Just like this:
``<style> h2.valentines {background-color: green; font-size: 50px; color: white;} </style>``
But remember to put it before the html elements you want to display.